# Using jQuery to rapidly scroll through a countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-plugins

I have a webpage that displays the number 0, and when the user presses "start", the number should rapidly increasing until it reaches a target number (maybe 10,000 or so) a few seconds later.  I'd like the numbers to scroll by as if they're on a slot machine wheel.

I've managed to mostly hack something together using the ScrollTo plugin, but it's slow and choppy.  It always stops briefly at certain divs along the way.  Perhaps I'm using it wrong.   Is there a better way to accomplish such an effect?

Answer (score 1):

May be  this plugin can help you
http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/